# Prove or disprove- $\int_{a}^\infty f^p(x) \text{d}x$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

> Given $f$ is positive and continuous on $[a,\infty)$ and
>   $\int_a^\infty f$ converges, does there exist $0<c<1$ such that for
>   all $c\leq p\leq 1$,  $\int_{a}^\infty f^p$ converges?

First of all I found this statement is true for functions of the kind $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^\alpha}$. Intuitively, taking the power of $p$ makes values of $f$ that are above 1 (which are still possible given $\int_a^\infty f$ converges) , decrease towards 1, and values of $f$ that are below 1, increase towards 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your idea of testing with functions $f_{\alpha} = x^{-\alpha}$, combined with the fact that taking power $p$ increases the function, note that $\int_a^{\infty} f$ converges for all $\alpha > 1$, but $\int_a^{\infty} f^p$ converges only when $\alpha p > 1$. Hence, $c > \frac 1 {\alpha}$. What can you conclude?

Comment: That the statement is true for this type of function, as I can take $c=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2\alpha}$ and then this is true for $1\geq p \geq \frac{1+\frac{1}{\alpha}}{2}>\frac{1}{\alpha}$. How does this help?

Comment: The point is that $\alpha$ isn't fixed. Vary $\alpha$ and see what happens.

Comment: But in the question I'm given a specific $f$ thus I may not change $\alpha$! I understand that in some sence, when $\alpha\rightarrow1$ the domanin for $p$ approaches $\emptyset$, but it's never exactly empty so it's still true.

Comment: Notice that you can also vary $f$. Take $f$ to be a sum of functions $x^{-\alpha_n}$ localized to certain intervals (plus whatever smoothing needs to happen to make it continuous). Or alternatively, take an $f$ that just *barely* has convergent integral, like a carefully chosen logarithmic perturbation of $1/x$.

Comment: The first suggestion I didn't understand at all.. About the 2nd one, taking $\frac{1}{x}$ doesn't work, and so does taking $\frac{1}{x^{1+\varepsilon}}$, so...?

Comment: @Theorem My point is that you ought to be able to come up with an example by either (i) taking some sum or combination of power functions that are closer and closer to the borderline or (ii) by figuring out a *particular* function that is right at the borderline, which is a perturbation of $x$ involving a **logarithm**. Not an exponent.

Comment: Is $\frac{1}{x \ln^2x}$ a good candidate?

Comment: @Theorem Yes, it is.